# Sometimes turns off randomly

Tags: controllers, mario-kart-8

For some reason, when I use a Wii Classic Controller Pro, the Wii Remote will turn off - and this only occurs when playing Mario Kart 8.

Comment: You've provided very little information for us to help you. Can you verify that this controller does not in fact turn off when playing other games?

Comment: I said it ONLY turns off in MK8. No other games.

Comment: Hey now, I'm trying to help. No need to get snarky. What other games have you tested this with? Have you tried changing the batteries on the wii-mote, or checking for corrosion?

Comment: Sorry - I tend to do things I don't mean to do. Anyways, there is Minecraft, Miiverse, Splatoon, and Mario Party 2 (Wii Virtual Console). And there is no corrosion.

Comment: Have you tried new batteries?

Comment: They work just fine, but thanks for suggesting that.

Comment: If you're not willing to try replacing them, then we're done here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42668/discussion-between-yoshilikes-and-kaizerwolf).